# How to create Sales rule (Coupon) in magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, frontend, backend, coupon

I created the coupon in function its works perfectly now I want to apply sales rules (apply on specific product) my code is

```
 public function setCoupon()
{
    // $this->_state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');  
    // $this->_state->setAreaCode('frontend');  


    // $coupon['name'] = 'Offer_asad17';
    $coupon['name'] = 'Sheikh';
    $coupon['desc'] = 'Discount for vip signup coupon.';
    $coupon['start'] = date('Y-m-d');
    $coupon['end'] = '';
    $coupon['max_redemptions'] = 1;
    $coupon['discount_type'] ='by_fixed';
    $coupon['discount_amount'] = 15;
    $coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
    $coupon['redemptions'] = 1;
    // $coupon['code'] ='NL017-1234'; //this code will normally be autogenerated but i am hard coding for testing purposes  
    $coupon['code'] ='Sheikh-1234'; //this code will normally be autogenerated but i am hard coding for testing purposes  

    $this->_rule->setName($coupon['name'])
            ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
            ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
            ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
            ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
            ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
            ->setIsActive(1)
            ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
            ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
            ->setDiscountQty(1)
            ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
            ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
            ->setWebsiteIds(array('1'))
            ->setCouponType(2)
             // ->setProductIds(array('1','2','3'))
            // ->setProductIds([1,2,3])
            // ->setProductIds(array(1,2,3))
            //->setProductIds([1,2,3])
            // ->setProductIds('1')
            ->setProductIds(1)
            ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
            ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);
    $this->_rule->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this my friend, this code to add rules before create coupon

```
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory;

protected $_ruleFactory;

public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        RuleFactory $ruleFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_ruleRepostitory = $ruleRepostitory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


public function execute()
    {
$ruleModel = $this->_ruleFactory->create();
$ruleModel->setName($getRule->getName())
                ->setDescription($getRule->getDescription())
                ->setCouponCode($getCoupon['code'])
                ->setFromDate($getRule->getFromDate())
                ->setToDate($getRule->getFromDate())
                ->setUsesPerCustomer($getRule->getUsesPerCustomer())
                ->setCustomerGroupIds($getRule->getCustomerGroupIds())
                ->setIsActive($getRule->getIsActive())
                ->setStopRulesProcessing($getRule->getStopRulesProcessing())
                ->setIsAdvanced($getRule->getIsAdvanced())
                ->setProductIds($getRule->getProductIds())
                ->setSortOrder($getRule->getSortOrder())
                ->setSimpleAction($getRule->getSimpleAction())
                ->setDiscountAmount($getRule->getDiscountAmount())
                ->setDiscountQty($getRule->getDiscountQty())
                ->setDiscountStep($getRule->getDiscountStep())
                ->setSimpleFreeShipping($getRule->getSimpleFreeShipping())
                ->setApplyToShipping($getRule->getApplyToShipping())
                ->setTimesUsed($getRule->getTimesUsed())
                ->setIsRss($getRule->getIsRss())
                ->setWebsiteIds($getRule->getWebsiteIds())
                ->setCouponType(2)
                ->setUsesPerCoupon($getRule->getUsesPerCoupon());
            $ruleModel->save();
```

}

**Remember, change " $getRule->... " = your data, good luck**